# reading integers and printing on pressing new line untill end of file in C++

Tags: c++

The program has to read a list of integers and print them as it is when we press enter up to endoffile (or ctrl+C)

ex:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
3 1 2 4
3 1 2 4

while(cin.get()!=-1){
                i=0;                
                while(1) {
                        if(cin.get()=='\n') {
                                break;
                        }
                        else {
                                cin >> a[i];
                                i++;
                        }
                }
                for(k=0;k<i;k++) {
                        cout << a[k]<< " ";
                                }
                }
```

but its not giving first integer, original output is as follows

ex:

```
 1 2 3 4
 2 3 4
 3 1 2 4
 1 2 4
```

How to improve this code in order to read and print first integer also .

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's wrong with just `std::string line; while ( std::getline( std::cin, line ) ) { std::cout << line << std::endl; }`.  It doesn't check for non-numbers, but you don't say what the program should do if the input isn't a number.

Answer (score 2):

`cin.get()` reads a character from the standard input and returns it . You do not assign the return value of `cin.get()` to a variable. Therefore, the value that was just read is lost.

Comment: is there any way to preserve it ?

Comment: Put it into a variable.

Comment: Do: char c; if ( (c = cin.get()) == '\n')

Answer (score 1):

Besides ignoring the result of get(), your code will end
in an infinite loop, if the input contains an invalid character
(if cin >> a[i] fails).

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Numbers: ";
    {
        std::string line;
        if(std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
            std::istringstream s(line);
            int number;
            while(s >> number) {
                std::cout << number << ' ';
            };
            // Consume trailing whitespaces:
            s >> std::ws;
            if( ! s.eof()) { std::cerr << "Invalid Input"; }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Digits: ";
    {
        std::istream::int_type ch;;
        while((ch = std::cin.get()) != std::istream::traits_type::eof()) {
            if(isdigit(ch)) std::cout << std::istream::char_type(ch) << ' ';
            else if(isspace(ch)) {
                if(ch == '\n')
                    break;
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "Invalid Input";
                break;
            }
        };
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the whole line and then parse it. One of the variants (with a minimum modifications to your code) is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i, k;
  char a[1024] = {0};
  string str;
  while(cin.good()){
    i=0;   
    getline(cin, str);
    stringstream ss(str);
    while (ss >> a[i]) { if (++i > 1024) break; }
    for(k=0;k<i;k++) {
      cout << a[k] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp ; echo -ne " 1 2 3 4\n5 6 7 8\n"|./main
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8
```